# Windows button Round corner in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, button, rectangles, rounded-corners

I'm using visual Studio 2015. I want to Create a rounded corner windows button in C#. Like this: 
[RoundedButton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SoHw.png)
I'm musing this code

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("Gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateRoundRectRgn")]
private static extern System.IntPtr CreateRoundRectRgn
(
    int nLeftRect,     // x-coordinate of upper-left corner
    int nTopRect,      // y-coordinate of upper-left corner
    int nRightRect,    // x-coordinate of lower-right corner
    int nBottomRect,   // y-coordinate of lower-right corner
    int nWidthEllipse, // height of ellipse
    int nHeightEllipse // width of ellipse
);

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "DeleteObject")]
private static extern bool DeleteObject(System.IntPtr hObject);

private void button1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    System.IntPtr ptr = CreateRoundRectRgn(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height, 15, 15); // _BoarderRaduis can be adjusted to your needs, try 15 to start.
    this.Region = System.Drawing.Region.FromHrgn(ptr);
    DeleteObject(ptr);
}
When I use this on `Form_paint`, it is working fine, but not working on `Button`.
```

When I use this on `Form_paint`, it is working fine, but not working on `Button`.

Comment: You are setting `this.Region`, which is the region for the form, rather than setting `button1.Region`, unless that's just a typo in your example.

Comment: thanks for your valuable time and knowledge. after correction button1.Region on this code, i am getting the result only on upper-left corner on this button. please share something about it.

Comment: You’re also setting the size of the region based on the size of the form rather that the size of the button.

Comment: Thank you very much......System.IntPtr ptr = CreateRoundRectRgn(0, 0, button1.Width, button1.Height, 15, 15);  button1.Region = System.Drawing.Region.FromHrgn(ptr); it's working fine.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are still getting the size for the rounded region from the whole form, rather than the button, and then you are applying the region to the form as well, rather than to the button.  So, in essence, by putting the region-manipulating code in the button's `Paint` event, you have changed *when* it's happening, but you haven't changed *what* it's doing.  Try this:

```
[DllImport("Gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateRoundRectRgn")]
private static extern System.IntPtr CreateRoundRectRgn
(
    int nLeftRect,     // x-coordinate of upper-left corner
    int nTopRect,      // y-coordinate of upper-left corner
    int nRightRect,    // x-coordinate of lower-right corner
    int nBottomRect,   // y-coordinate of lower-right corner
    int nWidthEllipse, // height of ellipse
    int nHeightEllipse // width of ellipse
);

[DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "DeleteObject")]
private static extern bool DeleteObject(System.IntPtr hObject);

private void button1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    IntPtr ptr = CreateRoundRectRgn(0, 0, button1.Width, button1.Height, 15, 15); 
    button1.Region = Region.FromHrgn(ptr);
    DeleteObject(ptr);
}
```